# How to remove Zombie birthdays from Contacts/Calendar?

Tags: calendar, contacts, gmail

I run [Contact Sync for Mac](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/41498/contacts-sync-for-google-gmail/download) to keep my Mac contacts in sync with my Google Contacts.

Occasionally this will delete contacts on the mac, that have been deleted as duplicates in Gmail. After Contact Sync deletes them - they can no longer be found in Contact Search.

But the duplicate contacts are still in my calendar as birthday entries. And when you click on the birthday the 'zombie contact' reappears in the Contacts (where they couldn't be searched before).

My question is: **How to remove Zombie birthdays from Contacts/Calendar?**